# Which part of the rendering pipeline compiles shaders?

Tags: graphics-card

Generally, video games and other graphical software that use vertex and fragment shaders will have said shaders in the form of actual shader source code (typically in glsl or hlsl), and will compile them for use with the display hardware at runtime. (It is my understanding that shaders cannot really be precompiled into the game binary because the actual shader machine code that the display hardware uses depends on the graphics card brand and even its model/generation, and they may well be incompatible with each other.)

Even though I do myself work on the game programming field and use shaders, I actually don't know exactly which part of the graphics pipeline actually compiles the shaders into the machine code that the graphics card uses. Compiling shaders is essentially a black box: Throw the shader source code into whatever library you are using, and it does its magic behind the scenes.

I would be interested in knowing exactly where this compiling process happens. Which exact part of the entire system takes the shader source code and produces shader machine code from it?

My (wild) guess is that this is done by the graphics card driver (because the driver knows what kind of machine code it should output, and how to optimize it, for the particular brand and model of graphics card).

(If this is indeed so, it would explain at least partially why the graphics driver is so crucial in how efficiently games run, as its optimization of the shader machine code would have great impact on rendering speed.)